# Fixing extruded mesh normals in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

In Unity C#, I'm using a procedular mesh extrusion, based on a flat polygon's 2D vector points. This works great using the code below, except for one detail: seemingly every second triangle which connects the front from the backside of the extruded mesh is flipped, as the image shows (using a double-sided shader, I can see all the triangles do exist fine, though). How would I fix the flip of these bridging normals? Thanks!

[image]

```
// Extrusion functionality via
// https://forum.unity.com/threads/trying-extrude-a-2d-polygon-to-create-a-mesh.102629/
// with Triangulator based on
// http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator

public static Mesh GetExtrudedMeshFromPoints(Vector2[] points, float depth)
{
    const float frontVertex = 0f;

    Triangulator triangulator = new Triangulator(points);
    int[] tris = triangulator.Triangulate();

    Mesh m = new Mesh();
    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[points.Length*2];

    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        vertices[i].x = points[i].x;
        vertices[i].y = points[i].y;
        vertices[i].z = frontVertex;
        vertices[i+points.Length].x = points[i].x;
        vertices[i+points.Length].y = points[i].y;
        vertices[i+points.Length].z = depth;
    }

    int[] triangles = new int[tris.Length*2+points.Length*6];
    int count_tris = 0;

    // Front vertices
    for (int i = 0; i < tris.Length; i += 3)
    {
        triangles[i]   = tris[i];
        triangles[i+1] = tris[i+1];
        triangles[i+2] = tris[i+2];
    } 

    count_tris += tris.Length;
    // Back vertices
    for (int i = 0; i < tris.Length; i += 3)
    {
        triangles[count_tris+i]   = tris[i+2] + points.Length;
        triangles[count_tris+i+1] = tris[i+1] + points.Length;
        triangles[count_tris+i+2] = tris[i]   + points.Length;
    }

    count_tris += tris.Length;
    // Triangles around the perimeter of the object
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        int n = (i+1) % points.Length;
        triangles[count_tris]   = i;
        triangles[count_tris+1] = i + points.Length;
        triangles[count_tris+2] = n;
        triangles[count_tris+3] = n;
        triangles[count_tris+4] = n + points.Length;
        triangles[count_tris+5] = i + points.Length;
        count_tris += 6;
    }

    m.vertices = vertices;
    m.triangles = triangles;

    m.RecalculateNormals();
    m.RecalculateBounds();
    m.Optimize();

    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a face isn't shown it is as you already noticed flipped, this is due to the winding order which in unity is clockwise. The link of your triangluator already states under Troubleshooting:
"If you can't see a polygon created with this utility, remember to check if the polygon is facing the opposite direction. If it is, you can change that by constructing your mesh with the vertex indices in reverse order."

**EDIT:**

for further clarification: in your code this would mean you have to switch

```
// Triangles around the perimeter of the object
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            int n = (i + 1) % points.Length;
            triangles[count_tris] = i;
            triangles[count_tris + 1] = i + points.Length;
            triangles[count_tris + 2] = n;
            triangles[count_tris + 3] = n;
            triangles[count_tris + 4] = n + points.Length;
            triangles[count_tris + 5] = i + points.Length;
            count_tris += 6;
        }
```

to

```
// Triangles around the perimeter of the object
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            int n = (i + 1) % points.Length;
            triangles[count_tris] = n;
            triangles[count_tris + 1] = i + points.Length;
            triangles[count_tris + 2] = i;
            triangles[count_tris + 3] = n;
            triangles[count_tris + 4] = n + points.Length;
            triangles[count_tris + 5] = i + points.Length;
            count_tris += 6;
        }
```

But be careful because the order depends on your depth (if it is higher or lower than you frontVertex)

**2nd EDIT:**

the normal of a triangle depends on the winding order, this means that there is a difference in the ordering.

An example:

```
1: Vector2(1f, 1f);
2: Vector2(1f, 0f);
3: Vector2(0f, 0f);
```

the triangle of

```
Triangle 1,2,3
```

and

```
Triangle 1,3,2
```

have different normal.

[image: Winding order of Triangles]

You have to make sure that the winding order is consistent for every triangle you draw.
Alternativly you could tell your shader to disable [culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html) (with `Cull Off`),as you already said above. But this comes with a cost of computation time. Which in most cases shouldn't matter that much, but it always depends on your purpose. Besides most of the time you dont want the side effects of disabling culling.

Comment: Hmm, on secondary tries, it only works sometimes, which is probably what you mention in your be-cafeful note. Wonder what I need to do to fix it for both cases?

Comment: You need to be sure that frontVertex is either always greater or always lesser than depth.
The easierst way would be an initial check if frontVertex > depth and if needed a switch of both parameters. In that case you wouldn't need to change the setup of your triangulation

Comment: Thanks. frontVertex is always 0f and depth is always 0.05f in my program, yet I'm having these issues. What to do?

Comment: This is due to the order of your triangles, either fix the order or the placement in the mesh (position of vertices). For further information look at my 2nd edit.

Comment: Thanks! How would I do that, fixing the winding order in the code library I'm using?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with that? you have to either fix the order how you add  the vertices to the mesh or the triangle order. how exactly you should so that i dont know, since i dont have the context of how your vertex and triangle list is generated

Comment: The code for the vertex and triangle list generation was in the question above (both the code itself, as well as the source URLs pointing to remaining code). It always takes as input a list of flat 2d points to extrude the mesh (points which could be adjusted if there's a helpful needed algo, they are generated by a user drawing so are unknown in advance). Thanks in any case!

Comment: yeah it was more about the points itself. How does the error look now? Does it have any noticable indicators? Likes does it only happen when the user draws from left to right, or from down to up. if you are able to identify what causes the flip you can create an if statement where you switch the placement of both points to change the winding order.

Comment: Now the issue looks like this: It's fine for many cases, and in many other cases the extruded mesh looks like it has all of the bridging extrusion triangles inverted. So instead of a zig-zag pattern as per above screenshot, the bridge normals are now either always correct or always wrong, seemingly. (I tried to pinpoint it to a reproducable pattern like drawing clockwise or counterclockwise but that didn't help reproduce it.)

Comment: that actually sounds like what i said in my earlier comment, happening when the user is drawing from left to right or up to down. you need to change the order you add your point into the list in these cases.

Comment: You might be exactly right! I think whatever needs to be done to the points to fix the issue would be the answer, and we might be close to it. If you want to, I can share the small & self-contained Unity source for this in some way (my email is philipp.lenssen@gmail.com). Here's a video of it, but the shader I'm using is double-sided and unlit, so it masks the actual issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZw3-yiZvjQ